# Manually type in a value in a "Select" / Drop-down HTML list?

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

In a Windows Forms application, a drop-down selector list also gives the user the option of typing an alternate value into that same field (assuming the developer has left this option enabled on the control.)

How does one accomplish this in HTML? It appears as if it is only possible to select values from the list.

If it's not possible to do this with straight HTML, is there a way to do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 59):

It can be done now with HTML5

See this post here [HTML select form with option to enter custom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650457/html-select-form-with-option-to-enter-custom-value)

```
<input type="text" list="cars" />
<datalist id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: It works for me well. In many cases we don't need to support old browsers. I only added "down arrow" image on the background of input field (you need an actual image file). <input type="text" list="cars" style="background:url('images/arrow_down.png') no-repeat right center">

Comment: It seems Chrome does the down arrow thing all by itself.

Comment: This seems really nice but options do not have an onclick trigger and you cannot pass any hidden values from options to input. So if you need to call a function with id for each option this is a real hustle. Also if youre looking for custom behavior like backspace clearing whole field it will cause unwanted behaviors.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same basic problem: trying to combine the functionality of a textbox and a select box which are fundamentally different things in the html spec.

The good news is that [selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) does exactly this:

> Selectize is the hybrid of a textbox and  box. It's jQuery-based and it's useful for tagging, contact lists, country selectors, and so on.

Comment: Played with almost all of the solutions and liked this one the best

Comment: The real MVP, you know who that is. Thanks for sharing that. Took me a while to find something portable like that after a lot of googling^W duck-duck-going around...

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to use jQuery : [jQuery UI combobox/autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: @Pretzel this doesn't need a license and is functionally equivalent to the ExtJS offering.

Comment: This almost works. In the example which asks a user to select a language. So I typed in "C#", but as soon as a click out of the combo-box, my entry goes away. I need to be able to write in custom answers. Not just ones in the Select List.

Comment: I think this is probably the best option here, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to wire it up to my HTML.

Answer (score 3):

[ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html) has a ComboBox control that can do this (and a whole host of other cool stuff!!)

EDIT: Browse all controls etc, here: http://www.sencha.com/products/js/

Comment: I think this may be what I'm looking for. Let me check it out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: This looks perfect, but it is not usable for me as I'm using it in-house for a private application and it requires me to purchase a license (which I probably cannot convince my boss to spring for.)  License here: http://www.sencha.com/license

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow one to enter a "custom" value.

Answer (score 2):

Another common solution is adding "Other.." option to the drop down and when selected show text box that is otherwise hidden. Then when submitting the form, assign hidden field value with either the drop down or textbox value and in the server side code check the hidden value.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c258Q/

HTML code:

```
Please select: <form onsubmit="FormSubmit(this);">
<input type="hidden" name="fruit" />
<select name="fruit_ddl" onchange="DropDownChanged(this);">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Apricot </option>
    <option value="melon">Peach</option>
    <option value="">Other..</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="fruit_txt" style="display: none;" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function DropDownChanged(oDDL) {
    var oTextbox = oDDL.form.elements["fruit_txt"];
    if (oTextbox) {
        oTextbox.style.display = (oDDL.value == "") ? "" : "none";
        if (oDDL.value == "")
            oTextbox.focus();
    }
}

function FormSubmit(oForm) {
    var oHidden = oForm.elements["fruit"];
    var oDDL = oForm.elements["fruit_ddl"];
    var oTextbox = oForm.elements["fruit_txt"];
    if (oHidden && oDDL && oTextbox)
        oHidden.value = (oDDL.value == "") ? oTextbox.value : oDDL.value;
}
```

And in the server side, read the value of "fruit" from the Request.

Answer (score 1):

I love the Shadow Wizard answer, which accually answers the question pretty nicelly. 
My jQuery twist on this which i use is here. http://jsfiddle.net/UJAe4/

After typing new value, the form is ready to send, just need to handle new values on the back end.

jQuery is:

```
(function ($) 
{
 $.fn.otherize = function (option_text, texts_placeholder_text) {
    oSel = $(this);
    option_id = oSel.attr('id') + '_other';
    textbox_id = option_id + "_tb";

    this.append("<option value='' id='" + option_id + "' class='otherize' >" + option_text + "</option>");
    this.after("<input type='text' id='" + textbox_id + "' style='display: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black' placeholder='" + texts_placeholder_text + "'/>");
    this.change(

    function () {
        oTbox = oSel.parent().children('#' + textbox_id);
        oSel.children(':selected').hasClass('otherize') ? oTbox.show() : oTbox.hide();
    });

    $("#" + textbox_id).change(

    function () {
        $("#" + option_id).val($("#" + textbox_id).val());
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

So you apply this to the below html:

```
<form>
    <select id="otherize_me">
        <option value=1>option 1</option>
        <option value=2>option 2</option>
        <option value=3>option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Just like this:

```
$(function () {

   $("#otherize_me").otherize("other..", "put new option vallue here");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik also has a combo box control. Essentially, it's a textbox with images that when you click on them reveal a panel with a list of predefined options.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

But this is AJAX, so it may have a larger footprint than you want on your website (since you say it's "HTML").