# HTML Datalist shows extra options separated by horizontal line

Tags: html, datalist

I am passing 10 options to datalist which are displayed fine in dropdown.
But sometime I am getting couple of more options separated by horizontal line at the bottom of option list(Chrome might be cacheing or displaying some option repeated). I am not able to get why chrome is showing these extra options separated by horizontal line

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went through different articles available on internet related to datalist and I came to know that datalist accepts autocomplete attribute. It give me a hint that extra options(might be - Previous searches, suggestions) I am getting are might be due to **autocomplete** feature of datalist, So I tried setting it to "**off**". 
Now I am not getting those extra option and horizontal line in option list anymore.
E.g. code snippet -

```
<input list="browsers" autocomplete="off">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I also came across one more attribute which datalist accepts, autocorrect="off". But I do not needed this attribute to resolve above problem.

Answer (score -2):

```css
option.select-hr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; }
```

```html
<select name="test">
    <option val="a">A</option>
    <option val="b" class="select-hr">B</option>
    <option val="c">C</option>
    <option val="d">D</option>
</select>
```

But generally speaking, the only method is to put an option in with dashes, and try to make it unselectable.

```html
<select name="test">
    <option val="a">A</option>
    <option val="b">B</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">----</option>
    <option val="c">C</option>
    <option val="d">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am not sure weather it will work for datalist as well,  But I will give it a try

Comment: this answer is not what the question is about. The question is not - how to add extra or dashed line - its about why its showing that extra line.