# Input type="text" with select functionality after clicking on Input type="text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have this piece of code:**
    `input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="" class="txt"`

This is a simple input.

**What I need.**
Click on this input type="text" **->** a drop-down select menu with several options appears (but it is still possible to write something manually into this input type="text") **->** click on any option **->** one of the options is inserted into the input type="text" **->** click again on the input type="text" **->** the same drop-down select menu with several options appears.

Please help to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML select form with option to enter custom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650457/html-select-form-with-option-to-enter-custom-value)

Comment: There is no a good answer on that page according to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with the standard form controls alone, but you can make your own. See the comments below for explanation.

```js
// Get references to elements used
var input = document.getElementById("selectedBrowser");
var list = document.getElementById("list");

// Get all the list items into an array
var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#list > div"));

// Make the "drop down" list the same width as the input
list.style.width = getComputedStyle(input).width;

// Set up click handler on the input
input.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
 list.classList.remove("hidden");  // Show the list
});

// Set up input event handler on input
input.addEventListener("input", function(){ 
 list.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide the list
});


// Loop over the list items
listItems.forEach(function(item){
  // Set up a click event handler
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    input.value = item.textContent;    // Copy the value into the input
   list.classList.add("hidden");       // Hide the list
  });

  // Set up a mouseover event handler
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    item.classList.add("highlight");       // Hide the list
  });
  
  // Set up a mouseout event handler  
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    item.classList.remove("highlight");       // Hide the list
  });
});
```

```css
/* Applied to the drop down list by default to hide it and
   removed when the list needs to be shown. */
.hidden {
 display:none;
}

#container {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

/* Ensures that the input will be positioned at the top-left of its parent */
#selectedBrowser {
  position:absolute;
}

#list {
  position:absolute; /* Position at top-left of parent */
  top:1.85em;  /* But, then move down to be below the input */
  border:1px solid #e0e0e0; 
  height:5em;  /* Limit height of list */
  overflow-y:scroll; /* Add vertical scroll bar when list won't fit in height */
}

#list > div {
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select:none;
  margin:2px 0;
}

.highlight {
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<label for="selectedBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label>
<div id="container">
  <input id="selectedBrowser" name="browser">
  <div id="list" class="hidden">
    <div>Chrome</div>
    <div>Firefox</div>
    <div>Internet Explorer</div>
    <div>Opera</div>
    <div>Safari</div>
    <div>Microsoft Edge</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a cross browser code. And it works only after second click on the input.

Comment: HTML5 is cross-browser with modern browsers. Are you saying you need to support IE 9?

Comment: Support IE9 - Yes, I need. And I need select menu after the first click. Not after the second.

Comment: And in Chrome I see a very strange behavior. Hover your mouse on this input from your example and you will see a black arrow. In Firefox I don't see this black arrow. And I don't need it in all other browsers including chrome.

Comment: Scott Marcus, Thank you very much for your update. But I don't see a classic select menu with the highlight of the options above which the cursor is located. And after typing something in the input the select menu should automatically disappear.

Comment: @williamzo I will add this, but these are not requirements you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @williamzo I have added that functionality. This is the only way you are going to be able to get what you are looking for. Any additional features you may want are just a matter of adding more event handlers and/or CSS.

Comment: Scott Marcus, Yeah, you are absolutely right. I didn't mention this, that's my fault. Hope your updated code will be a good solution of my problem and it will help not only to me.

Comment: Scott Marcus, your last update is perfect! And you are so fast, it's amazing! Now your code works perfect and completely solves the task that was described in my question.

Comment: Scott Marcus, I don't see how to mark your answer as "the" answer.

Comment: Scott Marcus, I'm looking for a developer for browser apps. Can I contact you?

Comment: Scott Marcus, I picked your answer as the best answer for my questions. Thanks again.

Comment: @williamzo If you look at my profile, on the top-right section, you'll see my website link. You can contact me from there.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a built-in `input` and a `datalist` that renders as a `combo box`. You add a `list` attribute to the `input` that matches the value of the `id` in the `datalist`. An example is shown below.

```
<input type="text" list="items" />
<datalist id="items">
  <option>Item1</option>
  <option>Item2</option>
  <option>Item3</option>
  <option>Item4</option>
</datalist>
```

An issue with this solution is that it is not supported by the Apple Safari browser. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) has the latest compatibility info.

If compatibility is an issue, a number of jQuery or javascript solutions are out there that may solve the problem. Here is a [link](http://www.baytree-cs.com/combo-select-box.html) to a Javascript solution that may work for you.

Comment: It's not a combox box that renders as an `input` and a `datalist`. It's an `input` and a  `datalist` that renders as a combo box. Also, try to find better references than W3 Schools, which is well-known to often have outdated, incomplete or flat out incorrect information. The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is well-known to be an authoritative source.

Comment: Of course, Safari compatibility is a BIG issue. Thank you for your link to a Javascript solution but I don't need any combo boxes. I don't need any arrows at the right of the input. I'll try to look better but from the first view your example don't solve my issue.