# How to create editable select field?

Tags: reactjs

How to create editable select Field in react?
I have below select field, please give me a solution.

```
      <Col lg={3} md={3} xs={6} sm={3} key="paycode">
            <Field
              name={`${actorExp}.apapaycode`}
              component={SelectField}
              options={tables.PAYS}
              onChange={this.handleBirthCountryChanged}
              readOnly={!modifiable}
              placeholder=               
              {formatMessage(actorMessages.countryPlaceHolder)}
              title={formatMessage(actorMessages.birthCountryTitle)}
              {...accessKeys[`${actorExp}.apapaycode`]}
              matchPos="start"
            />
      </Col>
```

In HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by editable select field ? You want to allow the user to autocomplete and filter the list manually ?

Comment: Maybe it will help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21958246/1374554