# How to fix code have use 20 datalist HTML tag with single database to show 1000 row in datalist but show only first 512 row in datalist?

Tags: php, html, html-datalist

How to fix code have use 20 datalist HTML tag with single database to show 1000 row in 20 datalist HTML tag but show only first 512 row in 20 datalist HTML tag?

Because I try coding but can't use 20 datalist HTML tag with single database to show 1000 row in 20 datalist HTML tag.

Sample code at the bottom.

1. `testdata.sql` (SQL Code)

```
CREATE TABLE `testdata` (
  `testdata` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `testdata` (`testdata`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11),
(12),
(13),
(14),
(15),
(16),
(17),
(18),
(19),
(20),
(21),
(22),
(23),
(24),
(25),
(26),
(27),
(28),
(29),
(30),
(31),
(32),
(33),
(34),
(35),
(36),
(37),
(38),
(39),
(40),
(41),
(42),
(43),
(44),
(45),
(46),
(47),
(48),
(49),
(50),
(51),
(52),
(53),
(54),
(55),
(56),
(57),
(58),
(59),
(60),
(61),
(62),
(63),
(64),
(65),
(66),
(67),
(68),
(69),
(70),
(71),
(72),
(73),
(74),
(75),
(76),
(77),
(78),
(79),
(80),
(81),
(82),
(83),
(84),
(85),
(86),
(87),
(88),
(89),
(90),
(91),
(92),
(93),
(94),
(95),
(96),
(97),
(98),
(99),
(100),
(101),
(102),
(103),
(104),
(105),
(106),
(107),
(108),
(109),
(110),
(111),
(112),
(113),
(114),
(115),
(116),
(117),
(118),
(119),
(120),
(121),
(122),
(123),
(124),
(125),
(126),
(127),
(128),
(129),
(130),
(131),
(132),
(133),
(134),
(135),
(136),
(137),
(138),
(139),
(140),
(141),
(142),
(143),
(144),
(145),
(146),
(147),
(148),
(149),
(150),
(151),
(152),
(153),
(154),
(155),
(156),
(157),
(158),
(159),
(160),
(161),
(162),
(163),
(164),
(165),
(166),
(167),
(168),
(169),
(170),
(171),
(172),
(173),
(174),
(175),
(176),
(177),
(178),
(179),
(180),
(181),
(182),
(183),
(184),
(185),
(186),
(187),
(188),
(189),
(190),
(191),
(192),
(193),
(194),
(195),
(196),
(197),
(198),
(199),
(200),
(201),
(202),
(203),
(204),
(205),
(206),
(207),
(208),
(209),
(210),
(211),
(212),
(213),
(214),
(215),
(216),
(217),
(218),
(219),
(220),
(221),
(222),
(223),
(224),
(225),
(226),
(227),
(228),
(229),
(230),
(231),
(232),
(233),
(234),
(235),
(236),
(237),
(238),
(239),
(240),
(241),
(242),
(243),
(244),
(245),
(246),
(247),
(248),
(249),
(250),
(251),
(252),
(253),
(254),
(255),
(256),
(257),
(258),
(259),
(260),
(261),
(262),
(263),
(264),
(265),
(266),
(267),
(268),
(269),
(270),
(271),
(272),
(273),
(274),
(275),
(276),
(277),
(278),
(279),
(280),
(281),
(282),
(283),
(284),
(285),
(286),
(287),
(288),
(289),
(290),
(291),
(292),
(293),
(294),
(295),
(296),
(297),
(298),
(299),
(300),
(301),
(302),
(303),
(304),
(305),
(306),
(307),
(308),
(309),
(310),
(311),
(312),
(313),
(314),
(315),
(316),
(317),
(318),
(319),
(320),
(321),
(322),
(323),
(324),
(325),
(326),
(327),
(328),
(329),
(330),
(331),
(332),
(333),
(334),
(335),
(336),
(337),
(338),
(339),
(340),
(341),
(342),
(343),
(344),
(345),
(346),
(347),
(348),
(349),
(350),
(351),
(352),
(353),
(354),
(355),
(356),
(357),
(358),
(359),
(360),
(361),
(362),
(363),
(364),
(365),
(366),
(367),
(368),
(369),
(370),
(371),
(372),
(373),
(374),
(375),
(376),
(377),
(378),
(379),
(380),
(381),
(382),
(383),
(384),
(385),
(386),
(387),
(388),
(389),
(390),
(391),
(392),
(393),
(394),
(395),
(396),
(397),
(398),
(399),
(400),
(401),
(402),
(403),
(404),
(405),
(406),
(407),
(408),
(409),
(410),
(411),
(412),
(413),
(414),
(415),
(416),
(417),
(418),
(419),
(420),
(421),
(422),
(423),
(424),
(425),
(426),
(427),
(428),
(429),
(430),
(431),
(432),
(433),
(434),
(435),
(436),
(437),
(438),
(439),
(440),
(441),
(442),
(443),
(444),
(445),
(446),
(447),
(448),
(449),
(450),
(451),
(452),
(453),
(454),
(455),
(456),
(457),
(458),
(459),
(460),
(461),
(462),
(463),
(464),
(465),
(466),
(467),
(468),
(469),
(470),
(471),
(472),
(473),
(474),
(475),
(476),
(477),
(478),
(479),
(480),
(481),
(482),
(483),
(484),
(485),
(486),
(487),
(488),
(489),
(490),
(491),
(492),
(493),
(494),
(495),
(496),
(497),
(498),
(499),
(500),
(501),
(502),
(503),
(504),
(505),
(506),
(507),
(508),
(509),
(510),
(511),
(512),
(513),
(514),
(515),
(516),
(517),
(518),
(519),
(520),
(521),
(522),
(523),
(524),
(525),
(526),
(527),
(528),
(529),
(530),
(531),
(532),
(533),
(534),
(535),
(536),
(537),
(538),
(539),
(540),
(541),
(542),
(543),
(544),
(545),
(546),
(547),
(548),
(549),
(550),
(551),
(552),
(553),
(554),
(555),
(556),
(557),
(558),
(559),
(560),
(561),
(562),
(563),
(564),
(565),
(566),
(567),
(568),
(569),
(570),
(571),
(572),
(573),
(574),
(575),
(576),
(577),
(578),
(579),
(580),
(581),
(582),
(583),
(584),
(585),
(586),
(587),
(588),
(589),
(590),
(591),
(592),
(593),
(594),
(595),
(596),
(597),
(598),
(599),
(600),
(601),
(602),
(603),
(604),
(605),
(606),
(607),
(608),
(609),
(610),
(611),
(612),
(613),
(614),
(615),
(616),
(617),
(618),
(619),
(620),
(621),
(622),
(623),
(624),
(625),
(626),
(627),
(628),
(629),
(630),
(631),
(632),
(633),
(634),
(635),
(636),
(637),
(638),
(639),
(640),
(641),
(642),
(643),
(644),
(645),
(646),
(647),
(648),
(649),
(650),
(651),
(652),
(653),
(654),
(655),
(656),
(657),
(658),
(659),
(660),
(661),
(662),
(663),
(664),
(665),
(666),
(667),
(668),
(669),
(670),
(671),
(672),
(673),
(674),
(675),
(676),
(677),
(678),
(679),
(680),
(681),
(682),
(683),
(684),
(685),
(686),
(687),
(688),
(689),
(690),
(691),
(692),
(693),
(694),
(695),
(696),
(697),
(698),
(699),
(700),
(701),
(702),
(703),
(704),
(705),
(706),
(707),
(708),
(709),
(710),
(711),
(712),
(713),
(714),
(715),
(716),
(717),
(718),
(719),
(720),
(721),
(722),
(723),
(724),
(725),
(726),
(727),
(728),
(729),
(730),
(731),
(732),
(733),
(734),
(735),
(736),
(737),
(738),
(739),
(740),
(741),
(742),
(743),
(744),
(745),
(746),
(747),
(748),
(749),
(750),
(751),
(752),
(753),
(754),
(755),
(756),
(757),
(758),
(759),
(760),
(761),
(762),
(763),
(764),
(765),
(766),
(767),
(768),
(769),
(770),
(771),
(772),
(773),
(774),
(775),
(776),
(777),
(778),
(779),
(780),
(781),
(782),
(783),
(784),
(785),
(786),
(787),
(788),
(789),
(790),
(791),
(792),
(793),
(794),
(795),
(796),
(797),
(798),
(799),
(800),
(801),
(802),
(803),
(804),
(805),
(806),
(807),
(808),
(809),
(810),
(811),
(812),
(813),
(814),
(815),
(816),
(817),
(818),
(819),
(820),
(821),
(822),
(823),
(824),
(825),
(826),
(827),
(828),
(829),
(830),
(831),
(832),
(833),
(834),
(835),
(836),
(837),
(838),
(839),
(840),
(841),
(842),
(843),
(844),
(845),
(846),
(847),
(848),
(849),
(850),
(851),
(852),
(853),
(854),
(855),
(856),
(857),
(858),
(859),
(860),
(861),
(862),
(863),
(864),
(865),
(866),
(867),
(868),
(869),
(870),
(871),
(872),
(873),
(874),
(875),
(876),
(877),
(878),
(879),
(880),
(881),
(882),
(883),
(884),
(885),
(886),
(887),
(888),
(889),
(890),
(891),
(892),
(893),
(894),
(895),
(896),
(897),
(898),
(899),
(900),
(901),
(902),
(903),
(904),
(905),
(906),
(907),
(908),
(909),
(910),
(911),
(912),
(913),
(914),
(915),
(916),
(917),
(918),
(919),
(920),
(921),
(922),
(923),
(924),
(925),
(926),
(927),
(928),
(929),
(930),
(931),
(932),
(933),
(934),
(935),
(936),
(937),
(938),
(939),
(940),
(941),
(942),
(943),
(944),
(945),
(946),
(947),
(948),
(949),
(950),
(951),
(952),
(953),
(954),
(955),
(956),
(957),
(958),
(959),
(960),
(961),
(962),
(963),
(964),
(965),
(966),
(967),
(968),
(969),
(970),
(971),
(972),
(973),
(974),
(975),
(976),
(977),
(978),
(979),
(980),
(981),
(982),
(983),
(984),
(985),
(986),
(987),
(988),
(989),
(990),
(991),
(992),
(993),
(994),
(995),
(996),
(997),
(998),
(999),
(1000);
```

2. `connect.php` (PHP Code)

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'mydatabase';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
?>
```

3. `testdata.php` (PHP Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php   
include ("connect.php");

    $db1 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db1, "utf8");

    if (!$db1) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db2 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db2, "utf8");

    if (!$db2) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db3 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db3, "utf8");

    if (!$db3) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db4 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db4, "utf8");

    if (!$db4) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db5 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db5, "utf8");

    if (!$db5) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db6 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db6, "utf8");

    if (!$db6) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db7 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db7, "utf8");

    if (!$db7) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db8 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db8, "utf8");

    if (!$db8) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db9 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db9, "utf8");

    if (!$db9) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db10 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db10, "utf8");

    if (!$db10) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db11 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db11, "utf8");

    if (!$db11) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db12 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db12, "utf8");

    if (!$db12) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db13 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db13, "utf8");

    if (!$db13) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db14 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db14, "utf8");

    if (!$db14) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db15 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db15, "utf8");

    if (!$db15) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db16 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db16, "utf8");

    if (!$db16) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db17 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db17, "utf8");

    if (!$db17) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db18 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db18, "utf8");

    if (!$db18) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db19 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db19, "utf8");

    if (!$db19) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
include ("connect.php");

    $db20 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($db20, "utf8");

    if (!$db20) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>

  <form>
    <div class="container">
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db1 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db1)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db2 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db2)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db3 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db3)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db4 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db4)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db5 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db5)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db6 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db6)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db7 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db7)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db8 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db8)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db9 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db9)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db10 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db10)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db11 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db11)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db12 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db12)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db13 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db13)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db14 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db14)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db15 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db15)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db16 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db16)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db17 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db17)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db18 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db18)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db19 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db19)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
          <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db20 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db20)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so many connections?  One will do. Why not use the same result set 20 times?  I didn't know that there was an upper limit for total datalist options.  Might you try a different approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902304/2943403

Comment: A matching report: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6519570?hl=en  What browsers are you testing on?

Comment: I worry that your sample data is not an accurate depiction of your application data.  I mean, if you are just presenting integers, why not use an `type = "number"` and declare the `min`, `max`, `step`?

Comment: Thanks you to introduce , I edit code with @mickmackusa introduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news 1** : I have answer to fix code "have use 20 datalist HTML tag with single database to show 1000 row in datalist but show only first 512 row in datalist" question because use Google Chrome to test code -> show only first 512 row in datalist and other browsers (Example : Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge Legacy) show all 1000 row in datalist and I wait Google to fix bug with [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=789187).

**Good news 2** : I have answer to connect only 1 database to use with any datalist HTML tag (in example use with 10 datalist HTML tag) with my full source code.

1. `testdata.sql` (SQL Code)

```
CREATE TABLE `testdata` (
  `testdata` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `testdata` (`testdata`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11),
(12),
(13),
(14),
(15),
(16),
(17),
(18),
(19),
(20),
(21),
(22),
(23),
(24),
(25),
(26),
(27),
(28),
(29),
(30),
(31),
(32),
(33),
(34),
(35),
(36),
(37),
(38),
(39),
(40),
(41),
(42),
(43),
(44),
(45),
(46),
(47),
(48),
(49),
(50),
(51),
(52),
(53),
(54),
(55),
(56),
(57),
(58),
(59),
(60),
(61),
(62),
(63),
(64),
(65),
(66),
(67),
(68),
(69),
(70),
(71),
(72),
(73),
(74),
(75),
(76),
(77),
(78),
(79),
(80),
(81),
(82),
(83),
(84),
(85),
(86),
(87),
(88),
(89),
(90),
(91),
(92),
(93),
(94),
(95),
(96),
(97),
(98),
(99),
(100),
(101),
(102),
(103),
(104),
(105),
(106),
(107),
(108),
(109),
(110),
(111),
(112),
(113),
(114),
(115),
(116),
(117),
(118),
(119),
(120),
(121),
(122),
(123),
(124),
(125),
(126),
(127),
(128),
(129),
(130),
(131),
(132),
(133),
(134),
(135),
(136),
(137),
(138),
(139),
(140),
(141),
(142),
(143),
(144),
(145),
(146),
(147),
(148),
(149),
(150),
(151),
(152),
(153),
(154),
(155),
(156),
(157),
(158),
(159),
(160),
(161),
(162),
(163),
(164),
(165),
(166),
(167),
(168),
(169),
(170),
(171),
(172),
(173),
(174),
(175),
(176),
(177),
(178),
(179),
(180),
(181),
(182),
(183),
(184),
(185),
(186),
(187),
(188),
(189),
(190),
(191),
(192),
(193),
(194),
(195),
(196),
(197),
(198),
(199),
(200),
(201),
(202),
(203),
(204),
(205),
(206),
(207),
(208),
(209),
(210),
(211),
(212),
(213),
(214),
(215),
(216),
(217),
(218),
(219),
(220),
(221),
(222),
(223),
(224),
(225),
(226),
(227),
(228),
(229),
(230),
(231),
(232),
(233),
(234),
(235),
(236),
(237),
(238),
(239),
(240),
(241),
(242),
(243),
(244),
(245),
(246),
(247),
(248),
(249),
(250),
(251),
(252),
(253),
(254),
(255),
(256),
(257),
(258),
(259),
(260),
(261),
(262),
(263),
(264),
(265),
(266),
(267),
(268),
(269),
(270),
(271),
(272),
(273),
(274),
(275),
(276),
(277),
(278),
(279),
(280),
(281),
(282),
(283),
(284),
(285),
(286),
(287),
(288),
(289),
(290),
(291),
(292),
(293),
(294),
(295),
(296),
(297),
(298),
(299),
(300),
(301),
(302),
(303),
(304),
(305),
(306),
(307),
(308),
(309),
(310),
(311),
(312),
(313),
(314),
(315),
(316),
(317),
(318),
(319),
(320),
(321),
(322),
(323),
(324),
(325),
(326),
(327),
(328),
(329),
(330),
(331),
(332),
(333),
(334),
(335),
(336),
(337),
(338),
(339),
(340),
(341),
(342),
(343),
(344),
(345),
(346),
(347),
(348),
(349),
(350),
(351),
(352),
(353),
(354),
(355),
(356),
(357),
(358),
(359),
(360),
(361),
(362),
(363),
(364),
(365),
(366),
(367),
(368),
(369),
(370),
(371),
(372),
(373),
(374),
(375),
(376),
(377),
(378),
(379),
(380),
(381),
(382),
(383),
(384),
(385),
(386),
(387),
(388),
(389),
(390),
(391),
(392),
(393),
(394),
(395),
(396),
(397),
(398),
(399),
(400),
(401),
(402),
(403),
(404),
(405),
(406),
(407),
(408),
(409),
(410),
(411),
(412),
(413),
(414),
(415),
(416),
(417),
(418),
(419),
(420),
(421),
(422),
(423),
(424),
(425),
(426),
(427),
(428),
(429),
(430),
(431),
(432),
(433),
(434),
(435),
(436),
(437),
(438),
(439),
(440),
(441),
(442),
(443),
(444),
(445),
(446),
(447),
(448),
(449),
(450),
(451),
(452),
(453),
(454),
(455),
(456),
(457),
(458),
(459),
(460),
(461),
(462),
(463),
(464),
(465),
(466),
(467),
(468),
(469),
(470),
(471),
(472),
(473),
(474),
(475),
(476),
(477),
(478),
(479),
(480),
(481),
(482),
(483),
(484),
(485),
(486),
(487),
(488),
(489),
(490),
(491),
(492),
(493),
(494),
(495),
(496),
(497),
(498),
(499),
(500),
(501),
(502),
(503),
(504),
(505),
(506),
(507),
(508),
(509),
(510),
(511),
(512),
(513),
(514),
(515),
(516),
(517),
(518),
(519),
(520),
(521),
(522),
(523),
(524),
(525),
(526),
(527),
(528),
(529),
(530),
(531),
(532),
(533),
(534),
(535),
(536),
(537),
(538),
(539),
(540),
(541),
(542),
(543),
(544),
(545),
(546),
(547),
(548),
(549),
(550),
(551),
(552),
(553),
(554),
(555),
(556),
(557),
(558),
(559),
(560),
(561),
(562),
(563),
(564),
(565),
(566),
(567),
(568),
(569),
(570),
(571),
(572),
(573),
(574),
(575),
(576),
(577),
(578),
(579),
(580),
(581),
(582),
(583),
(584),
(585),
(586),
(587),
(588),
(589),
(590),
(591),
(592),
(593),
(594),
(595),
(596),
(597),
(598),
(599),
(600),
(601),
(602),
(603),
(604),
(605),
(606),
(607),
(608),
(609),
(610),
(611),
(612),
(613),
(614),
(615),
(616),
(617),
(618),
(619),
(620),
(621),
(622),
(623),
(624),
(625),
(626),
(627),
(628),
(629),
(630),
(631),
(632),
(633),
(634),
(635),
(636),
(637),
(638),
(639),
(640),
(641),
(642),
(643),
(644),
(645),
(646),
(647),
(648),
(649),
(650),
(651),
(652),
(653),
(654),
(655),
(656),
(657),
(658),
(659),
(660),
(661),
(662),
(663),
(664),
(665),
(666),
(667),
(668),
(669),
(670),
(671),
(672),
(673),
(674),
(675),
(676),
(677),
(678),
(679),
(680),
(681),
(682),
(683),
(684),
(685),
(686),
(687),
(688),
(689),
(690),
(691),
(692),
(693),
(694),
(695),
(696),
(697),
(698),
(699),
(700),
(701),
(702),
(703),
(704),
(705),
(706),
(707),
(708),
(709),
(710),
(711),
(712),
(713),
(714),
(715),
(716),
(717),
(718),
(719),
(720),
(721),
(722),
(723),
(724),
(725),
(726),
(727),
(728),
(729),
(730),
(731),
(732),
(733),
(734),
(735),
(736),
(737),
(738),
(739),
(740),
(741),
(742),
(743),
(744),
(745),
(746),
(747),
(748),
(749),
(750),
(751),
(752),
(753),
(754),
(755),
(756),
(757),
(758),
(759),
(760),
(761),
(762),
(763),
(764),
(765),
(766),
(767),
(768),
(769),
(770),
(771),
(772),
(773),
(774),
(775),
(776),
(777),
(778),
(779),
(780),
(781),
(782),
(783),
(784),
(785),
(786),
(787),
(788),
(789),
(790),
(791),
(792),
(793),
(794),
(795),
(796),
(797),
(798),
(799),
(800),
(801),
(802),
(803),
(804),
(805),
(806),
(807),
(808),
(809),
(810),
(811),
(812),
(813),
(814),
(815),
(816),
(817),
(818),
(819),
(820),
(821),
(822),
(823),
(824),
(825),
(826),
(827),
(828),
(829),
(830),
(831),
(832),
(833),
(834),
(835),
(836),
(837),
(838),
(839),
(840),
(841),
(842),
(843),
(844),
(845),
(846),
(847),
(848),
(849),
(850),
(851),
(852),
(853),
(854),
(855),
(856),
(857),
(858),
(859),
(860),
(861),
(862),
(863),
(864),
(865),
(866),
(867),
(868),
(869),
(870),
(871),
(872),
(873),
(874),
(875),
(876),
(877),
(878),
(879),
(880),
(881),
(882),
(883),
(884),
(885),
(886),
(887),
(888),
(889),
(890),
(891),
(892),
(893),
(894),
(895),
(896),
(897),
(898),
(899),
(900),
(901),
(902),
(903),
(904),
(905),
(906),
(907),
(908),
(909),
(910),
(911),
(912),
(913),
(914),
(915),
(916),
(917),
(918),
(919),
(920),
(921),
(922),
(923),
(924),
(925),
(926),
(927),
(928),
(929),
(930),
(931),
(932),
(933),
(934),
(935),
(936),
(937),
(938),
(939),
(940),
(941),
(942),
(943),
(944),
(945),
(946),
(947),
(948),
(949),
(950),
(951),
(952),
(953),
(954),
(955),
(956),
(957),
(958),
(959),
(960),
(961),
(962),
(963),
(964),
(965),
(966),
(967),
(968),
(969),
(970),
(971),
(972),
(973),
(974),
(975),
(976),
(977),
(978),
(979),
(980),
(981),
(982),
(983),
(984),
(985),
(986),
(987),
(988),
(989),
(990),
(991),
(992),
(993),
(994),
(995),
(996),
(997),
(998),
(999),
(1000);
```

2. `connect.php` (PHP Code)

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'mydatabase';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
?>
```

3. `testdata.php` (PHP Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php   
    include ("connect.php");

    $db1 = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    mysqli_set_charset($db1, "utf8");

    if (!$db1) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>

  <form>
    <div class="container">
  <input list="testdata" name="testdata">
  <datalist id="testdata">
    <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db01 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers);

    foreach ($db01 as $d1) {
        echo "<option value='".$d1['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata2" name="testdata2">
  <datalist id="testdata2">
          <?php
    $queryusers2 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db02 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers2);

    foreach ($db01 as $d2) {
        echo "<option value='".$d2['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata3" name="testdata3">
  <datalist id="testdata3">
    <?php
    $queryusers3 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db03 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers3);

    foreach ($db01 as $d3) {
        echo "<option value='".$d3['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata4" name="testdata4">
  <datalist id="testdata4">
    <?php
    $queryusers4 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db04 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers4);

    foreach ($db04 as $d4) {
        echo "<option value='".$d4['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata5" name="testdata5">
  <datalist id="testdata5">
    <?php
    $queryusers5 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db05 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers5);

    foreach ($db1 as $d5) {
        echo "<option value='".$d5['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata6" name="testdata6">
  <datalist id="testdata6">
    <?php
    $queryusers6 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db06 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers6);

    foreach ($db06 as $d6) {
        echo "<option value='".$d6['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata7" name="testdata7">
  <datalist id="testdata7">
    <?php
    $queryusers7 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db07 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers7);

    foreach ($db07 as $d7) {
        echo "<option value='".$d7['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata8" name="testdata8">
  <datalist id="testdata8">
    <?php
    $queryusers8 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db08 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers8);

    foreach ($db08 as $d8) {
        echo "<option value='".$d8['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata9" name="testdata9">
  <datalist id="testdata9">
    <?php
    $queryusers9 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db09 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers9);

    foreach ($db09 as $d9) {
        echo "<option value='".$d9['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
  <input list="testdata10" name="testdata10">
  <datalist id="testdata10">
    <?php
    $queryusers10 = "SELECT * FROM `testdata` ";
    $db10 = mysqli_query($db1, $queryusers10);

    foreach ($db10 as $d10) {
        echo "<option value='".$d10['testdata']."'></option>";
    }
    ?>
</datalist><br><br>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```