# How to create a html select tag where option being a text input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a `html select tag` where first option is a `input` element but it is not working.

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option ><input type="text"></option>
    <option >Saab</option>
    <option >Opel</option>
  </select>
```

I want to take input from the first option and based on the input change the other option. But can not add the first option as input field. How do i do this?

Comment: @adiga it's useful when you want to make a search inside the select box

Comment: It's the requirement. I have no option. It would be much easier if I could put it outside select ta

Comment: If you just want search, there are native solutions: [HTML select form with option to enter custom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650457)

Comment: Otherwise, you'd have to use a library: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage