# Manually type in value in Multiple Drop down lists

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create multiple drop-down selector lists on a webpage which also give the user an option of typing alternate values. I found a solution here: [Manually type in a value in a "Select" / Drop-down HTML list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430262/manually-type-in-a-value-in-a-select-drop-down-html-list)

The answer posted by user "pawelmech" works with a single dropdown list, but i couldn't make it work with multiple dropdowns. Any help would be appreciated.

JQuery:

```
(function ($) 
{
 $.fn.otherize = function (option_text, texts_placeholder_text) {
    oSel = $(this);
    option_id = oSel.attr('id') + '_other';
    textbox_id = option_id + "_tb";

    this.append("<option value='' id='" + option_id + "' class='otherize' >" + option_text + "</option>");
    this.after("<input type='text' id='" + textbox_id + "' style='display: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black' placeholder='" + texts_placeholder_text + "'/>");
    this.change(

    function () {
        oTbox = oSel.parent().children('#' + textbox_id);
        oSel.children(':selected').hasClass('otherize') ? oTbox.show() : oTbox.hide();
    });

    $("#" + textbox_id).change(

    function () {
        $("#" + option_id).val($("#" + textbox_id).val());
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select class="otherize_me">
        <option value=1>option 1</option>
        <option value=2>option 2</option>
        <option value=3>option 3</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
    <select class="otherize_me">
        <option value=4>option 4</option>
        <option value=5>option 5</option>
        <option value=6>option 6</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
    <select class="otherize_me">
        <option value=7>option 7</option>
        <option value=8>option 8</option>
        <option value=9>option 9</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ak0dje2/)

Comment: `id` value has to be unique. Use class or another selector.

Comment: Can you plz create a jsfiddle demo for me?

Answer (score 0):

`id` value has to be unique. Use class or another selector.  Updated code to expand the example.

HTML :

```
<form>
    <select id="otherize_me_1">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select id="otherize_me_2">
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
        <option value="5">option 5</option>
        <option value="6">option 6</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select id="otherize_me_3">
        <option value="7">option 7</option>
        <option value="8">option 8</option>
        <option value="9">option 9</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.otherize = function (option_text, texts_placeholder_text) {
        var oSel = $(this);
        var option_id = oSel.attr('id') + '_other';
        var textbox_id = option_id + "_tb";

        oSel.append("<option value='' id='" + option_id + "' class='otherize' >" + option_text + "</option>");
        oSel.after("<input type='text' id='" + textbox_id + "' style='display: none;' placeholder='" + texts_placeholder_text + "'/>");
        oSel.change(function () {
            oTbox = $('#' + textbox_id);
            oSel.children(':selected').hasClass('otherize') ? oTbox.show() : oTbox.hide();
        });

        $("#" + textbox_id).change(function () {
            $("#" + option_id).val($(this).val());
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

$(function () {
    $("#otherize_me_1").otherize("Other..", "Other1");
    $("#otherize_me_2").otherize("Other..", "Other2");
    $("#otherize_me_3").otherize("Other..", "Other3");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d16m548s/)

Comment: Thanks mate, It seems to be working but there is still a problem. Input type box should only be displayed if the "Other.." option is seleted. Can you fix it? –

Comment: @Albert expanded the answer further to work a full example.  The code you currently have relies on element ids to identify where to add the textbox and to load the value back. The sample should work as expected now.

Comment: @Albert you need to learn a bit about javascript and html before continuing.  Without some understanding of the method, applying it to your needs would be very difficult.  The sample you have provided does not indicate any hindrance to unique id values.