# AngularJS drop-down with ability to type value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown

We're using AngularJS v1.5.8 in our application. I am looking for a way to display drop down but also allow to type new value. I've checked this [Manually type in a value in a "Select" / Drop-down HTML list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430262/manually-type-in-a-value-in-a-select-drop-down-html-list) and tried datalist (didn't work in Google Chrome) and also looked at the http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ and http://jsfiddle.net/69wP6/4/  I am wondering if something already exists for angularJs so I would not re-invent the wheel.

My current code is this

```html
 <input type="text" name="newRowValue" id="newRowValue" class="form-control" 
                       list="rowValues" ng-model="newRowValue"
                       placeholder="@Labels.typeOrSelect"/>
                <datalist id="rowValues" name ="rowValues"
                    class="form-control" ng-model="rowValue">
                    <option ng-repeat = "possibleValue in metaData.allPossibleValues| filter: {attributeId: currentMatrixTemplate.rowAttributeId}" 
                            value="{{possibleValue.attributeId}}" ng-show="possibleValue.hidden==false || showHidden">{{possibleValue.valueName}} 

                   </option>
                </datalist>
```

which doesn't render correctly in Chrome. Any ideas for good and simple implementation of drop down with ability to type new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. We use our version of this, but it's very close to [this solution.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I need http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/ - will try it.

Comment: I've checked documentation and samples but I don't see the sample for my case. I need to be able to select a value and also to type the value and  be able to add that value

Comment: @naomi look at this page:http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-select2-with-bootstrap.html. This is the new version, but looks like the old.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I just implemented my own solution which I think should be sufficient for my case. E.g. simply placed drop-down on the form and input text above with ng-show = property which was false initially. Then I set this property to true in drop-down ng-keydown event (only when 'other' is selected) and back to false when I am done with that textbox and added the value. Works OK although not very fancy.