# Disallow input if it matches predefined values

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to disallow certain input into an html input field.

[Manually type in a value in a "Select" / Drop-down HTML list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430262/manually-type-in-a-value-in-a-select-drop-down-html-list) this question covers how to recommend values while letting the user type.

I would like to let the user type and 'blacklist' certain values if they matches one of my predefined values and show a warning.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: On each keyup change you'd need to check if the current text matches a certain word, if it does then remove the word and show a warning underneath maybe? It's perfectly doable, show us what you've tried and the exact problems you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  const val = e.value;
  const blacklist = ["12345678", "qwerty"];
  if (blacklist.indexOf(val) >= 0) alert("Blacklist");
}
```

```html
<p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
```

You need to play with `keyup` event and provide a blacklist. You can do whatever you want with `val`, you could check if it's one of blacklist values(example above) or if it matches a RegExp pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression. It's only possible to submit the form if the text does not contain *foo*.

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="xx" pattern="^((?!foo).)*$"><br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```